# How can i write this class component to react functional component.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

Iam trying to write my component to react function but i cant format it properly and my classes and styles dosent apllied on it what is the proper way to convert this component. My all other code is in a fuctions and i also want this to be a functional component

My Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Tab from './Tab';

class Tabs extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array).isRequired,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeTab: this.props.children[0].props.label,
    };
  }

  onClickTabItem = (tab) => {
    this.setState({ activeTab: tab });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      onClickTabItem,
      props: {
        children,
      },
      state: {
        activeTab,
      }
    } = this;

    return (
      <div className="tabs">
        <ol className="tab-list">
          {children.map((child) => {
            const { label } = child.props;

            return (
              <Tab
                activeTab={activeTab}
                key={label}
                label={label}
                onClick={onClickTabItem}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ol>
        <div className="tab-content">
          {children.map((child) => {
            if (child.props.label !== activeTab) return undefined;
            return child.props.children;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tabs;
```

Comment: Where is the code for what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Tab from './Tab';

export default function Tabs ({ children }){
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(children[0].props.label);

  function onClickTabItem(tab){
    setActiveTab({ activeTab: tab });
  }

  return (
    <div className="tabs">
      <ol className="tab-list">
        {children.map((child) => {
          const { label } = child.props;

          return (
            <Tab
              activeTab={activeTab}
              key={label}
              label={label}
              onClick={onClickTabItem}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ol>
      <div className="tab-content">
        {children.map((child) => {
          if (child.props.label !== activeTab) return undefined;
          return child.props.children;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Tabs.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some explanations what your code does.

Comment: export default function -> i'm exporting the module.

funcion Tabs ({ children }) i'm destructuring the props  and getting the prop children.

WIthout destructuring would be like: function Tabs(props)

In functional components, the state can be called with useState.

I recommend that you to study react doc :)
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: The above answer is ok but whenever i click on the other tab it dosent works

Answer (score 0):

So what you wanna do is remove the `render`  and the `constructor` since their is no `render` and `constructor` in functional component and the next thing you wanna do is use the `useState` hook to maintain the state variables.Furthermore , you could pull out `children` from the `props` passed to the components and for static properties on a function you declare them on the function itself so instead of using `static propTypes` you would use `Tabs.propTypes`

```
        import React from "react";
        import PropTypes from "prop-types";

        import Tab from "./Tab";

        const Tabs = props => {


          const { children } = props;

          const [state, setState] = useState({
            activeTab: props.children[0].props.label
          });

          const onClickTabItem = tab => {
            setState({ activeTab: tab });
          };

          return (
            <div className='tabs'>
              <ol className='tab-list'>
                {children.map(child => {
                  const { label } = child.props;

                  return (
                    <Tab
                      activeTab={state.activeTab}
                      key={label}
                      label={label}
                      onClick={()=>onClickTabItem()}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </ol>
              <div className='tab-content'>
                {children.map(child => {
                  if (child.props.label !== activeTab) return undefined;
                  return child.props.children;
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        };
   //Static Props
     Tabs.propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array).isRequired
      };


    export default Tabs;
```